# APA format values for `baselineskip`, `parskip`, `parindent`, and other such values

Tags: apa-style, books

I would like my book to have an APA format writing in LaTeX. What values should I change to make such a format?
Preamble code that might be relevant:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

Comment: You may be interested in the [`apa7`](https://ctan.org/pkg/apa7) document class (or in [`apa6`](https://ctan.org/pkg/apa6) if you need 6th ed. APA formatting). Of course those classes do a lot more than just paragraph spacing, but at the very least you could have a quick look at the code to see which values they use.

Comment: Not working. I use Overleaf if that helps.